# (Internal) Fire looks blocky in final render

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine, smoke-simulation

So I took a sphere, made it a smoke simulator, added wind and increased that to 50.00, and rendered it. For some reason it looks very pixelated.
3D Viewport:
[image]

Final Render:
[image]

Blender File:

[image]

Comment: The problem is most likely in your shader settings, since it only affects the render. Could you add a screenshot of those, or post a .blend (without the environment geo)?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using any sort of volume shader. That's probably the problem.

Comment: So how would I add one? I'm working in internal by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You could activate high resolution.

[image]